# Trouble Outside WordPress with mobile site

Tags: php, wordpress

This is my problem, I try to get the data outside wordpress with this two instructions in a mobile site:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('blog/wp-blog-header.php');
```

When I get into one of the pages that have these two instructions on iPhone and Android, the page redirects me to the home or index of the full site.

You can try and see this link: http://www.121govideo.com/121govideom on your mobiles.
Can anyone help me with this problem?.

Answer (score 0):

Use `wp-load.php` instead of `wp-blog-header.php`.